# How to setup a rule at compile time in Tasmota

Tags: compilation, rules, tasmota

I want a rule to start the Wifi Manager when a button is long-pressed. I enter the following rule on the web console or serial, it works fine:

```
Rule 1 on button1#state=3 do wificonfig 2 endon
```

And to enable the rule:

```
Rule1 1
```

I tried to bake this rule into my build at compile time:

```
#undef USER_RULE1
#define USER_RULE1 "on button1#state=3 do wificonfig 2 endon"
```

This does not work. So my questions are:

1. Should I include the word 'rule1' also within the command string ? That is,

   #define USER_RULE1 "Rule1 on button1#state=3 do wificonfig 2 endon"
2. Should I enable the rule also within this string. I am not sure where to put the 'Rule1 1' part to enable it. Can it be like:

   #define USER_RULE1 "Rule1 on button1#state=3 do wificonfig 2 endon Rule1 1"

Neither of them looks convincing to me.
Can someone please point me to the documentation/ examples for compile time rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question.
Seems like the answer is here:
https://tasmota.github.io/docs/Compile-your-build/#advanced-customization

In your case, it should be:

```
#define USER_BACKLOG "Rule1 1"
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you.
For my question1, the answer is NO; you need not have the prefix 'Rule 1'.

For question 2, the solution is:
 
#define USER_BACKLOG "Rule1 1"

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit lost.
When I compile in my rule and the activation of this rule1 in USER_BACKLOG then I see in the log after flashing, that the rule is activated, but it’s not coming to execution, because it’s deactivated from some process during startup again. If I activate it manually after again, the rule is working like expected, only not directly after flashing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).